# Turning Off Exits in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So ive got the map looking pretty much how I want it, other than 4 exits above Ericsson place. I havent been able to find the correct reference material on googles api site to fix this issue.
I would like to either get rid of them overall or turn them back to there normal shade of green with the exit numbers (1,2,3..) in white.
http://jsfiddle.net/DKEhf/1/

```
styles:[
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "labels",  stylers: [ { color: "#FD5E0F" } ] },
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { weight: "0.5" }, { lightness: "20" } ] },
    { featureType: "landscape", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [ { color: "#FF7F50" }, { lightness: "70" } ] },
    { featureType: "road.highway", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },
    { featureType: "administrative.land_parcel",  stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?